# Rename file as third word on it (bash)

Tags: linux, bash, rename, filenames, txt

I have several autogenerated files (see the picture below for example) and I want to rename them according to 3rd word in the first line (in this case, that would be 42.txt).

First line:

*ligand CC@@HOc3ccccc3   **42**  P10000001*

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: How are the words separated? Exactly one space, or an arbitrary number of spaces, or a tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you have `file.txt` containing:

```
ligand CC@@HOc3ccccc3 42 P10000001
```

and you want to rename `file.txt` to `42.txt` based on the 3rd field in the file.

***Using `awk`**

The easiest way is simply to use `mv` with `awk` in a *command substitution*, e.g.:

```bash
mv file.txt $(awk 'NR==1 {print $3; exit}' file.txt).txt
```

Where the *command-substitution* `$(...)` is just the `awk` expression `awk 'NR==1 {print $3; exit}'` that simply outputs the 3rd-field (e.g. `42`). Specifying `NR==1` ensures only the first line is considered and `exit` at the end of that rule ensures no more lines are processed wasting time if `file.txt` is a 100000 line file.

**Confirmation**

`file.txt` is now renamed `42.txt`, e.g.

```
$ cat 42.txt
ligand CC@@HOc3ccccc3 42 P10000001
```

**Using `read`**

You can also use `read` to simply read the first line and take the 3rd word as the `name` there and then `mv` the file, e.g.

```bash
$ read -r a a name a <file.txt; mv file.txt "$name".txt
```

The temporary variable `a` above is just used to read and discard the other words in the first line of the file.